# Process.start environment path

Tags: c#, process.start

I have console application 1 which write text to file and it is in C:/app1

```
using (StreamWriter k = new StreamWriter("777.txt"))
    k.WriteLine("aa");
```

I have another console application 2, c:/app2, which start console application 1

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:/app1/app1.exe");
```

For some reason, when I run application 2, the output 777.txt will be in folder2 instead of folder1. When I run application 1 from windows explorer, the output 777.txt will be in folder1.

I look and tried to add environment.path but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\app1\app1.exe");
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory= @"c:\app1";

        Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your application 1 is using a relative path, not a rooted path. That path is relative to the "current directory", not the "path" environment variable.

Process can accept a ProcessStartInfo instance which includes a property to define the current directory. You'll want to set that to the location of application 1 before starting it.

Answer (score 1):

you should replace your `"777.txt"` with `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "777.txt"`